# How and why are all the substituents in methyl cyclopropane eclipsed?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why does [methyl cyclopropane $\ce{C3H5CH3}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylcyclopropane) adopt an [eclipsed conformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipsed_conformation)?

Answer (score 0):

The geometry of the molecule is highly restricted by the presence of the ring.

[image]

The presence of the ring caused the $\ce{C-C-C}$ ring to be planar, because every triangle is planar.

Since there is only one carbon atom directly to the right to the circle, it must be eclipsed, so are the hydrogen atoms by VSEPR.

Comment: How do you know that "the carbons atoms are eclipsed?"

Comment: Because there is only one carbon atom, so it must be eclipsed.

Comment: From which perspective are you looking at the molecule? I see 4 carbon atoms, not one carbon atom.

Comment: I have just clarified.

Comment: why can't cyclopropane pucker and be fluxional to relieve the torisional strain like cyclobutane does?

Comment: Why can't cyclopropane be staggered instead of eclipsed?

Comment: Because the $\ce{C}$ is already eclipsed. There isn't two $\ce{C}$s, there is just one $\ce{C}$.

Comment: If cyclopropane were to arrange itself in a isosceles, right, or equilateral triangle, which one of the three triangular shapes would be the most stable?

Comment: bring up my comment please.

Comment: also include scalene, obtuse, and acute triangles and all types of  triangles that exist

Comment: For example, In cyclopropane, would one angle close to 109.5 degrees and the rest of the angles 70.5 degrees each, be more stable than all angles at 60 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Drawing a Newman projection shows that the H atoms are eclipsed. Due to its shape, cyclopropane can never exist in a staggered conformation. Note that what looks like a double bond is actually the bond between the carbon on the back to the carbon on top.

Comment: why can't cyclopropane pucker and be fluxional to relieve the torisional strain like cyclobutane does?